# Session compression. Negative and positive sides

Tags: asp.net

In web.config you can enable session compression.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" compressionEnabled="true" >
```

What are positive and negative sides of this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on the positive side, you need less space. 
On the negative side, it needs time to compress, so it's slower.

Let me add, that in my opinion, if you use sessions at all, you've made an architectural mistake (exceptions my apply to this rule, but very very rarely).

It's not a good idea, because if a page writes something in a session, this gets overwritten if I simultanously open the same page in another browser window (it's the same session). 
And because InProc sessions expire when you change something in the web.config file, you can create unlimited number of bugs for EVERY currently active user...
Plus you loose inProc sessions, if the VM gets moved to another server (cloud environments, failover, dynamic scaleOut).

Also, the InProc provider doesn't require objects to be marked as serializable. 
If you change to, for example, an SQL session provider, you'll get exceptions in all places where you put an object that hasn't been marked as serializable into the session.

For example, when you need to query all the locations a user may access (according to portofolio rights in T_SYS_LocationRights):

You get the UserID from the formsAuth-cookie, then use it as the parameter:

```
DECLARE @userID integer 
SET @userID = 12435


SELECT * FROM T_Locations 
WHERE (1=1) 
AND
( 
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(T_SYS_LocationRights.LR_IsRead AS integer)), 0) 
        FROM T_SYS_LocationRights 

        INNER JOIN T_User_Groups 
            ON T_User_Groups.USRGRP_GRP = T_SYS_LocationRights.LR_GRANTEE_ID 

        WHERE T_SYS_LocationRights.LR_LC_UID = T_Locations.LC_UID 
        AND T_User_Groups.USRGRP_USR = @userID  
    ) = 1 
)
```

Don't just query something after the maxim:

> if you'll ever need it, it's already there.

Design a web-application (which is multi-threaded by design) after that maxim, is a very bad idea.

- If you don't need it, don't query it.
- If you need it, query it.
- If you needed it, don't store it in the session, it's better to query it again, if necessary

You can win much more time by executing all database operations at once, get all the data you need into a System.Data.DataSet (in one query-operation, one connection open-and-close), and then use that. When the page reloads, you can always reload the data (as a matter of fact, you even should).

- Don't use the session as cache. It's not the cache

Comment: So where would you save, for example USER custom rights, which are saved in session["UserRights"] from database table when you are logining into page?

Comment: @user2179088: I wouldn't save them. Get the UserID from the authentication cookie, and query the database when you need the info. Don't store it, else you can change the user's rights, but it has no effects until the existing session expires (if you'd take it from the session).